# Where to use CosmosDB?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

CosmosDb has a good feature of Globally Distributed which gives Faster Response of data.  This will be useful for Mobile Applications directly accessing CosmosDb where Users are spread across the Globe.

However I am using ASP.NET Web Application hosted in Azure.  Here my Application to Database communication will be of Fixed Distance always.

Can I benefit from CosmosDb in this case?

This is for Azure hosted ASP.NET Application

Comment: i think you describe two different cases. Either your mobile app will communicate with the azure backend (and the backend will communicate with db) or mobile app will communicate with db by itself. These are different cases

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize CosmosDB when you know noSQL concept and so is your code, it has different implementation for read and write processes or you are planning to do microservices or you have other projects that depends/communicate on your Webapp project and your using the same database

Answer (score 0):

There are some points you need to take into account before choosing CosmosDB as the database.

1. Pricing model! CosmosDB is not a cheep database and pricing model is based on the provisioned throughput. Requests that exceed the provisioned throughput will be rejected by the database. So first make sure you completely understand how things work.
2. Like other document based databases, if you wanna keep a graph of objects in a document, you should consider how to handle concurrent updates to the documents (if that is the case in your app). Hope you know well the difference between document based and relational databases.

But regarding the benefits:

1. It has a great a integration support with other PaaS services in Azure
2. It scales very well if you have a good partitioning strategy